# What are the programming languages used to develop a GitHub App or an OAuth App?

Tags: git, github

But just to clarify I'm not talking about a real app that would replace or alternate GitHub's functionality.

I'm talking about an app that extends and uses the functionality of GitHub, according to: http://developer.github.com/apps/marketplace

I'm not really familiar with developing an application as an extension of another application, but based on what I have read it can support node.JS as its programming language.

But just out of curiosity, and that is for those who are very familiar this this topic, are those types of apps written in any programming languages other than node.JS. as its primary language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand it, GitHub does not run nor host the applications for you. That's your responsibility.

[GitHub Apps use the GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/apps/available-endpoints/), either REST v3 or GraphQL v4, to speak to GitHub. And GitHub uses [webhooks](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/) to send GitHub events to your app. Any programming language that can make and receive HTTPS requests and work with JSON can write a GitHub App.

Basically you're writing a little web API app.

Comment: Nice! Thank you for the clarification.